# Cannot declare date variable in correct format for sql query in Python

Tags: python, sql-server, date

Executing an sql query using Python and feeding in a date variable for the select. But I am getting the error 'datetime2 is incompatible with int (206)' I have mucked around with the variable but can't seem to get it into the correct format. Code below:

```
import pyodbc
import pandas as pd
import datetime

dt = datetime.date(2021, 10, 1)
print (dt)

server = 'testServer'
database = 'testDatabase'
username = 'test'
password = '{test}'   
driver= '{ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server}'

conn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER='+driver+';SERVER=tcp:'+server+';PORT=1433;DATABASE='+database+';UID='+username+';PWD='+ password)

conn.autocommit = True

select_sql = """Select * From test Where Inception <= {x}""".format(x=dt)

sql_query = pd.read_sql_query(select_sql, conn)
```

Comment: That is because you arent quoting the date. Look at the output of `select_sql` and run that query in sql server to see why the error is. Also, you should use parameterized statement instead of string concatenation.

Comment: Why not use parameters, rather than injection? Injection is **dangerous**.

Comment: Thank you. When I do quote the date I get the same error if you mean quote the date as '2021-10-01'. What would be an example of using parameterisation here. Sorry not very experienced at coding.

Comment: Also, if you do parametrise your parameters *(seems so silly when you say that doesn't it?)* this problem doesn't even exist.

Comment: [This link](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Getting-started#parameters) will help you write parameterized query to get the records from DB. Why you are  using pandas to query is beyond me. I dont know if pandas support reading data from sql server using pyodbc.

Comment: @Larnu thank you. So that should sort it. im using pandas as I want to create a dataframe later on in the process. What is your suggestion there?

Comment: @CGarden: My bad. I think you may use pandas to read data into a dataframe. I hope my comment helps you in getting the data out of sql server using parameterized statement.

Comment: Thanks @shahkalpesh much appreciated

Comment: Sorry in the example it talks about applying parametrization using cursor.execute(), but I don't know how to apply this to pd.read_sql_query(). Thank you.

Comment: Used this ```sql_query = pd.read_sql_query(select_sql, conn, params=[dt])```, which fixed the issue. Thank you. Why does parametrization fix the issue out of interest?

Comment: @shahkalpesh do you want to put this as the answer and I will mark it so. Thanks.

Comment: @CGarden: No, that is okay. You may try searching stackoverflow in future because questions such as yours have been asked. Searching skills are important too :)

Comment: Too true :) thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pointed significantly in the right direction by @shahkalpesh (thank you), using this parametrization solved the issue with the date. `"""Select * From test Where Inception <= ?""" sql_query = pd.read_sql_query(select_sql, conn, params=[dt])`